# How to uncheck checkbox immediately?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have this HTML code:

```
<tr *ngFor="let stud of [1,2,3]">
    <mat-checkbox (change)="setPupilAbsence($event)"></mat-checkbox>
</tr>
```

And handler:

```
public setPupilAbsence(event: MatCheckbox): void {
      event.checked = false;
}
```

Comment: Elaborate your problem statement .

Comment: Whats not working?

Comment: When I click over checkbox I call this handler, then I try to uncheck checkbox immidiatly using reference $event: `event.checked = false;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `event.checked` property is probably immutable or only there for read purposes. Also, the event is not the `MatCheckbox` itself, but it is `MatCheckboxChange`.

You can use the source of the event: `event.source.checked = false;`

```
import {MatCheckboxChange} from '@angular/material';
...
setPupilAbsence(event: MatCheckboxChange) {
    event.source.checked = false;
}
```

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pnjymr)

Comment: Pass this instead  `MatCheckbox` as parameter?

Comment: @OPV Sorry for the wrong Stackblitz URL. I've updated it.